# Regex matching multiple groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am very new to Regex and trying to create filter rule to get some matches. For Instance, I have query result like this:

```
application_outbound_api_external_metrics_service_plus_success_total
application_outbound_api_external_metrics_service_plus_failure_total
application_inbound_api_metrics_service_success_total
application_inbound_api_metrics_service_failure_total
```

Now I want to filter ONLY lines which contains "outbound" AND "service_plus" AND "failure".

I tried to play with groups, but how can I create an regex, but somwhere I am misundersteanding this which contains in wrong results.

Regex which I used:

```
/(?:outbound)|(?:service_plus)|(?:failure)/
```

Comment: `|` is _alternation_ in regex - so you are not demanding that _all_ of those must occur, but only at least one of them.

Comment: And how can I demand all of them?

Comment: By listing them in the correct order, and allowing arbitrary other stuff in between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multiple lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=.*outbound)(?=.*service_plus)(?=.*failure).*\n?
```

The above should use the MULTILINE flag so that `^` is interpreted as start of string or start of line.

1. `^` - matches start of string or start of line.
2. `(?=.*outbound)` - asserts that at the current position we can match 0 or more non-newline characters followed by 'outbound` without consuming any characters (i.e. the scan position is not advanced)
3. `(?=.*service_plus)` - asserts that at the current position we can match 0 or more non-newline characters followed by 'service_plus` without consuming any characters (i.e. the scan position is not advanced)
4. `(?=.*failure)` - asserts that at the current position we can match 0 or more non-newline characters followed by 'failure` without consuming any characters (i.e. the scan position is not advanced)
5. `.*\n?` - matches 0 or more non-line characters optionally followed by a newline (in case the final line does not terminate in a newline character)

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3p31Et/1)

In Python, for example:

```py
import re

lines = """application_outbound_api_external_metrics_service_plus_success_total
application_outbound_api_external_metrics_service_plus_failure_total
application_inbound_api_metrics_service_success_total
application_inbound_api_metrics_service_failure_total
failureoutboundservice_plus"""

rex = re.compile(r'^(?=.*outbound)(?=.*service_plus)(?=.*failure).*\n?', re.M)

filtered_lines = ''.join(rex.findall(lines))
print(filtered_lines)
```

Prints:

```None
application_outbound_api_external_metrics_service_plus_failure_total
failureoutboundservice_plus
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of lookaheads to assert that multiple things need to exist regardless of the order they exist:

```
^(?=.*(?:^|_)outbound(?:_|$))(?=.*(?:^|_)service_plus(?:_|$))(?=.*(?:^|_)failure(?:_|$)).+$
```

- `^` - start line anchor
- `(?=` - open the positive lookahead aka "ahead of me is..."

  - `.*` - optionally anything
  - `(?:^|_)` - start line anchor or underscore
  - `outbound` - the word "outbound"
  - `(?:_|$)` - underscore or end line anchor
  - The underscores and line anchors ensure we don't have false positives like "outbounds" or "goutbound"
- `)` - close the positive lookahead
- Rinse and repeat for "service_plus" and "failure"
- Since we haven't captured any chars yet, the second and third lookaheads allow for searching the terms in any order
- `.+$` - capture everything till the end of the line

https://regex101.com/r/Zhl4Mf/1

---

If the order does matter then build a regex in the correct order:

```
^.*_outbound_.*_service_plus_failure_.*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/b7O5YK/1

Comment: Could you please provide explanation for the expressions? It is a little bit hard to me to understeand it and I would love to understeand it.

Comment: @WinterMute I documented the first regex. I assume you understood the second regex.